# Upgrade/install Java version in a Mac

Tags: java, macos, yum, apt-get

I am on a Mac. My current `Java` version is  "1.6.0_65". Therefore i want to upgrade it to the latest. I typed the following command on my Mac `terminal`.

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

The error i got is `sudo: apt-get: command not found`. Then i tried using `yum` command instead. and the error i got it `sudo: yum: command not found`.

1.) Is there a way to install `apt-get` and `yum` on Mac, if so how?

2.) What is the command to upgrade Java using a Mac?

Comment: 1.) No, they don't work on Mac. 2.) Download from Oracle's site and run the installer.

Comment: Mac OS X is based on [BSD](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution) Unix, not Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sudo apt-get is for Ubuntu or Debian, no for Mac. You only need to download java from Oracle or Apple servers and install!!

You can download this http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1573

Comment: No, Yum is for other Unix distro http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowdog_Updater,_Modified, no for Mac

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides a Java 6 implementation for Mac OS X, based on source code from Oracle's implementation.

Oracle provides a Java 7 implementation that incorporates source code provided by Apple. Apple staff cooperate in its development.

The old URL, nice and short, redirects to Oracle's download page:

http://java.sun.com/

From there navigate to the Java SE download page. Download JRE to run Java software. Download JDK if you want to develop new Java software. Download and run an installer app.

Currently that page URL is:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Oracle also provides an early release of Java 8 for Mac OS X.